# how to get sub folder list and how verify the folder name exist or not using CSOM ,C#

Tags: client-object-model

i have to verify the subfolder names if not there in that list how to create dyanamically using CSOM and C#

Answer (score 8):

How to determine whether Folder exists

```
/// <summary>
/// Determine if Folder exists 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="web"></param>
/// <param name="listTitle"></param>
/// <param name="folderUrl"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static bool FolderExists(Web web, string listTitle, string folderUrl)
{
    var list = web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
    var folders = list.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllFoldersQuery());
    web.Context.Load(list.RootFolder);
    web.Context.Load(folders);
    web.Context.ExecuteQuery();
    var folderRelativeUrl = string.Format("/{0}/{1}", list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl, folderUrl);
    return Enumerable.Any(folders, folderItem => (string) folderItem["FileRef"] == folderRelativeUrl);
 }
```

How to create Folder

```
/// <summary>
/// Create Folder
/// </summary>
/// <param name="web"></param>
/// <param name="listTitle"></param>
/// <param name="folderName"></param>
private static void CreateFolder(Web web,string listTitle, string folderName)
{
    var list = web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
    var folderCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation
    {
        UnderlyingObjectType = FileSystemObjectType.Folder,
        LeafName = folderName
    };
    var folderItem = list.AddItem(folderCreateInfo);
    folderItem.Update();
    web.Context.ExecuteQuery();
 }
```

Usage

```
using (var context = new ClientContext(url))
{
    var listTitle = "Documents";      
    var folderName = "Orders"; 
    if (!FolderExists(context.Web, listTitle, folderName))
    {
        CreateFolder(context.Web, listTitle, folderName);
    }
}
```

Comment: I found that I needed to change FolderExists to use list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl instead of list.RootFolder.Name

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using this [blog post](http://ranaictiu-technicalblog.blogspot.in/2010/03/sharepoint-2010-manage.html):

```
public void CreateFolder(string siteUrl, string listName, string relativePath, string folderName)

{

    using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl))

    {

        Web web = clientContext.Web;

        List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle(listName);


        ListItemCreationInformation newItem = new ListItemCreationInformation();

        newItem.UnderlyingObjectType = FileSystemObjectType.Folder;

        newItem.FolderUrl = siteUrl + "/lists/" + listName;

        if (!relativePath.Equals(string.Empty))

        {

            newItem.FolderUrl += "/" + relativePath;

        }

        newItem.LeafName = folderName;

        ListItem item = list.AddItem(newItem);

        item.Update();

        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    }

}
```

then we can use it like:

```
CreateFolder("http://server", "mylist", "", "myfolder");
```

or

```
CreateFolder("http://server", "mylist", "myfolder", "mysubfolder");
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Vadim Gremyachev the code works great but I also have to change the line:

```
var folderRelativeUrl = string.Format("/{0}/{1}", list.RootFolder.Name, folderUrl);
```

for:

```
var folderRelativeUrl = string.Format("{0}/{1}", list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl, folderUrl);
```